# Proguard configuration for Android Support v4 22.2.0

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, proguard

After updating dependencies on Gradle Android build to use `com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0` from local Maven extras repository (within SDK), Proguard started throwing these problems.

```
Warning: android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment$DialogStyle
Warning: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction$Transit
Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$ResolvedLayoutDirectionMode
Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$LayoutDirectionMode
Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$LayerType
Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$AccessibilityLiveRegion
Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$ImportantForAccessibility
Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OverScroll
Warning: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$EdgeGravity
Warning: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LockMode
Warning: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$State
Warning: there were 11 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
```

Simply adding `-dontwarn android.support.v4.**` solves the problem, but I'd like an more specific/elegant solution, than ignoring all problems on support.v4 package

Can anybody tell what rules should be added, so these classes/@interfaces are correctly processed by Proguard?

Comment: even i faced this issue a lot of times, 
but the only solution i could is using `-dontwarn`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only solution is what you have mentioned, i.e `-dontwarn android.support.v4.**`. This is actually taken from the `<path-to-android-sdk>/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt`, where it says:

```
# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

Answer (score 4):

It is safe to set don't warn for the support library classes according to the Android team. You can do this via:

```
## Support library
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

Comment: What problem? Is your app crashing?

Comment: No, but the build is, and that worries me

Comment: Isn't that just due to warnings?

Comment: Yes, but warnings aren't without reason, it's to me like ignoring Lint warnings

Comment: @MarekSebera the answer is given by Google itself in the `proguard-android.txt` inside **<path-to-android-sdk>/tools/proguard/**. It says `# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.`

Comment: @Sufian well I checked and you're right, was not aware of this file. Thank you!

Comment: @Sufian make your comment into answer and I'll accept it as correct answer, this answer is not entirely same as the contents of `proguard-android.txt`, so it's your chance