# After update Android studio and compile with api 23 could not generate release apk

Tags: android

After update Android studio and compile with api `23` could not generate `release apk` showing following warning after include

-`dontwarn android.support.v4.`

-`dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers`

in build.gradle

**Warning:** there were 5 unresolved references to library class members.         You probably need to update the library versions.         Alternatively, you may have to specify the option

```
'-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'
```

(http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)

**Warning:** Exception while processing task

`java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings`

`first.:dazzledCars:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease`

**FAILEDError:** `Execution failed for task ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.`

> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31564183

Comment: Thanks but I already did this.

Comment: Its compile fine .But show error when generate release apk

Comment: Any solution for this?